# localStorage.getItem('user') is null

Tags: angular, typescript

I start to learn angular and I am new to the web.
I have a member-list component that I need to use information about user,
the course that I follow, used this line to retriev user but mine is null.
I dont have any idea to where should check to see what is wrong.

```js
//user
User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

error:
[image]

Comment: Please post more related to your code, simply by one line of code its hard to figure out. Like the format of ``user``, then are you even using ``localStorage.setItem('user')``, etc.

Comment: you have to SAVE a user to localStorage, before you can retrieve it.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading and learning some basic concepts of web before diving into Angular or any framework.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should **store** the values in **localstorage** using `localstorage.setItem()` in order to retrieve the values using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Thanks, I did not set item any where. solved!